# Emacs screen tearing with mouse scroll

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs 25.1 under Red Hat Linux and recently discovered that my Emacs will have a screen tearing issue if I scroll the text with mouse.[image: Sample image of A Tale of Two Cities]

The issue does not occur if I use key board to scroll: C+V, M+V or C+L. And the tearing could be solved if I `M-X redraw-display`.

This issue is still annoying as I will from time to time use my mouse. Any suggestions or settings that I should try to avoid this issue?

Further background: I am connected to a server on a Windows 10 machine (Thinkpad T460s). Emacs 24.3 works fine under same platform.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: My crystal ball suggests maybe you're using an X server under Windows, and some of those are apparently regular sources of odd behaviors.

Comment: @Stefan, how do I know if I am using X server?